# XML Deserialization of complex object

Tags: c#, .net, xml-deserialization

I have xml structure like this:

```
<Group id="2" name="Third" parentid="0" />
<Group id="6" name="Five" parentid="4" />   
<Group id="3" name="Four" parentid="2" />
<Group id="4" name="Six" parentid="1" />
```

parent is denotes Group's Id.

The Constructor of Group reads like:

```
public Group(string name, int ID, Group parent)
```

While De-serializing, how do I get parent using Id and pass into group?

Comment: This seems like a misuse of XML - the whole point is that it is structured!  You seem to be using it like  a flat file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the inbuilt processing, then `XmlSerializer` only really wants to use the default constructor. You could do that via:

```
public class Group {
    public Group() {}

    [XmlAttribute("id")]
    public int Id {get;set;}
    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string Name {get;set;}
    [XmlAttribute("parentid")]
    public int ParentId {get;set;}
}
```

but note that there is a big difference between a `Group` parent and a parent-id. I suspect the best approach would be to *either* write the data in a more hierarchical fashion, *or* to stick with what you have, but use a simple DTO during deserialization. Then translate this data into what you *actually* want in the next stage. So, if you have:

```
List<GroupDTo> groups = ...
```

You might translate that as:

```
var actualGroups = from group in groups
                   select new Group(group.Id, group.Name,
                      groups.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == group.ParentId));
```

this should do what you need.